How to retrieve specific match statistics using Hockey OpenAPI schema?
I am trying to retrieve specific match statistics using the Hockey OpenAPI schema provided at https://hockey.sportdevs.com/matches-statistics?match_id=eq.{match_id}. However, I am facing difficulties in fetching the data for a particular match.
I have tried passing the match_id parameter in the URL to retrieve the match statistics, but I am not getting the expected results. I expect to receive the statistics for the specified match, but instead, I am getting an empty response.
const matchId = '12345';
fetch(`https://hockey.sportdevs.com/matches-statistics?match_id=eq.${matchId}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));


Have you checked the status code you are receiving?
The example you posted is missing authentication headers and results in a 401 (Unauthorized) status code. You can see how to authenticate here.
Using fetch it would look like this if using SportDevs authentication:
const matchId = '12345';

// https://docs.sportdevs.com/docs/sportdetect_authentication_hockey
const SPORT_DEVS_API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN_HERE';

fetch(
  `https://hockey.sportdevs.com/matches-statistics?match_id=eq.${matchId}`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${SPORT_DEVS_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  },
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));

